# focused product -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example:

> You Need an Oracle ACE
>   Oracle partners, developers, and customers look to Oracle ACEs and Oracle ACE Directors for **focused product** expertise, systems and solutions discussion,
>   and informed opinions on a wide range of data center implementations. Their credentials are strong as Oracle product and technology experts, community enthusiasts, and solutions advocates. And now is a great time to learn more about this elite group—or nominate a worthy colleague.

Does anyone here know what the term *focused product* means? I looked online, but it was very difficult to make sense of all the information I dug up. It seems like no one out there can really explain or has a clear explanation as to what it is.

Comment: I think the word *focused* modifies *product expertise* entirely rather than *product*. I think it means that those ACEs and ACE Directors are supposed to have excellent and precise knowdledge/expertise of their products.

Comment: Goodness gracious, it's an advertisement. It doesn't have to mean anything, it just has to sound like it means something. People don't actually read it.

Comment: @stoneyb Have you ever hung around advertising people? They obsess over the meaning and connotations of every word. At one company I worked for they agonized over whether to say "comfort" or "comfortable". I am quite sure that very few consumers analyze each word of an ad and ponder its meaning. I wonder if there is really some subtle subconscious effect that these advertising experts can use to manipulate us, or if advertising people are just nuts.

Comment: @Jay  This doesn't look like agency work to me. Agency work involves Real Writers, it's usually crisp and (dare I say it?) focused on benefits to a particular audience. It makes you want to read it. This random collection of noun phrases looks to me like something written by corporate management, with perhaps a little massaging by the marketing department.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Focused" is not modifying "product"; it's modifying "expertise". Their expertise is focused on this product. That is, these are people who know all about this product. They may or may not know anything about other products, but their goal, their intent, their focus, is on this product.